# .js form not working

Tags: java, javascript, forms, submit

well i have got this Themeforest Template and played around with it until the website looks in a way how i imagined it. The only Problem i have is that the .js form somehow doesnt work and i dont have any idea. I dont even know where to tell the form to which Adress it should send the text. Maybe you can help me.

The Domain is: entwicklung.thechillingbull.de

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container"> </div>
<div class="container"> </div>
<div class="bg-2 section" id="contact">
  <div class="inner" data-topspace="50" data-bottomspace="20" data-image="flavours/coffeecream/images/demo-content/background-6.jpg">
    <div class="container">
      <h3 class="hdr4">Kontakt und Reservierung</h3>
      <div class="easyBox full">
        <div class="row nomargin">
          <div class="col-md-11">
            <h4 class="hdr2 special">Wenn du Uns etwas mitteilen oder Reservieren möchtest hast du hier die Chance!</h4>
            <form class="simpleForm" action="form/form.php" method="post">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Dein Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_[]" placeholder="Schreibe deinen Namen">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Deine E-Mail-Adresse</label>
                  <input type="email" required class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Schreibe deine E-Mail-Adresse">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Deine Nachricht</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="field_[]" placeholder="Schreibe deine Nachricht"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="msg_subject" value="Contact Form">
                <input type="hidden" name="field_[]" value=" ">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Senden">
              </fieldset>
            </form>
            <div class="successMsg" style="display:none;">Nachricht erfolgreich gesendet! </div>
            <div class="errorMsg" style="display:none;"> Ups! Es ist ein Fehler unterlaufen, versuche es später erneut. </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the .js

```
/**
 * Submitting Form
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var debug = false; //show system errors
    var sendingMessage = 'Sending...';


    $('.simpleForm').submit(function () {
        var $f = $(this);
        var $submit = $f.find('input[type="submit"]');

        //prevent double click
        if ($submit.hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }

        $submit.attr('data-value', $submit.val()).val(sendingMessage).addClass('disabled');

        $.ajax({
            url: $f.attr('action'),
            method: 'post',
            data: $f.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                if (data.errors) {
                    // error
                        var $errorMsg = jQuery($f).parent().find(".errorMsg");
                            jQuery($f).fadeOut(300,function(){
                                $errorMsg.fadeIn();
                            });

                } else {
                        // success
                        var $successMsg = jQuery($f).parent().find(".successMsg");
                            jQuery($f).fadeOut(300,function(){
                                $successMsg.fadeIn();
                            });
                }

                $submit.val($submit.attr('data-value')).removeClass('disabled');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                if (debug) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }
                $submit.val($submit.attr('data-value')).removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

hope you can help me get this to work.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<form class="simpleForm" action="form/form.php" method="post">
```

To

```
<form class="simpleForm" action="/your-code-file" method="post">
```

where `your-code-file` will be the location of the file which will handle the form values.